# Prestashop error on product page after domain name change

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

After i changed the domain name of my prestashop instalation i can't connect to admin anymore. I tried debug mod then i was able to connect to admin but there was errors an my products page:

```
(1/1) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined index: lng

in e50d7a72e070bd5681c93bfa420e5d7bf7ce90e8_2.file.product.tpl.php line 635
at Block_5636438495bf032887165a3_21987681->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 247
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_5636438495bf032887165a3_21987681), object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 183
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_5636438495bf032887165a3_21987681), object(Block_15679221315bf0326619f255_83923016))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 185
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_15679221315bf0326619f255_83923016))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 157
```

Can someone help to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try to delete all cache folder ?

Comment: Yes i tried manualy to empty /cache/smarty/compile/ /cache/smarty/cache/ /cache/cachefs/

Comment: Is it only in your admin ? Because if it's in the frontend, you might just check if index lng of this array used in the template exists with something like isset() function.

Answer (score 0):

try clean cache in `var/cache/ or app/cache`
And check PHP version !

Regards